# How to merge two dataframes and return data from another column in new column only if there is match?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a two df that look like this:

```
df1:

id
1
2


df2:

id    value
2       a
3       b
```

How do I merge these two dataframes and only return the data from `value` column in a new column if there is a match?

```
new_merged_df

id   value   new_value
1
2     a         a
3     b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this using @JJFord3 setup:

```
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame(index=[1,2])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'value' : ['a','b']},index=[2,3])

#Use isin to create new_value   
df2['new_value'] = df2['value'].where(df2.index.isin(df1.index))
#Use reindex with union to rebuild dataframe with both indexes
df2.reindex(df1.index.union(df2.index))
```

Output:

```
  value new_value
1   NaN       NaN
2     a         a
3     b       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame(index=[1,2])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'value' : ['a','b']},index=[2,3])

new_merged_df_outer = df1.merge(df2,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
new_merged_df_inner = df1.merge(df2,how='inner',left_index=True,right_index=True)
new_merged_df_inner.rename(columns={'value':'new_value'})
new_merged_df = new_merged_df_outer.merge(new_merged_df_inner,how='left',left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

First, create an outer merge to keep all indexes.
Then create an inner merge to only get the overlap.
Then merge the inner merge back to the outer merge to get the desired column setup.

Comment: There may be a more efficient way to do this, but given you want both the inner and outer representation I think this is the most straight-forward way to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2,on='id',how='outer')

id_value = df2.loc[df2['id'].isin(df1.id.tolist()),'id'].unique()
mask = df['id'].isin(id_value)
df.loc[mask,'new_value'] = df.loc[mask,'value']
# alternative df['new_value'] = np.where(mask, df['value'], np.nan)    

print(df)
   id value new_value
0   1   NaN       NaN
1   2     a         a
2   3     b       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full outer join`

Lets model your data with case classes:

```
case class MyClass1(id: String)
case class MyClass2(id: String, value: String)

//  this one for the result type
case class MyClass3(id: String, value: Option[String] = None, value2: Option[String] = None)
```

Creating some inputs:

```
val input1: Dataset[MyClass1] = ...
val input2: Dataset[MyClass2] = ...
```

Joining your data:

```
import scala.implicits._
val joined = input1.as("1").joinWith(input2.as("2"), $"1.id" === $"2.id", "full_outer")

joined map {
  case (left, null) if left != null => MyClass3(left.id)
  case (null, right) if right != null => MyClass3(right.id, Some(right.value))
  case (left, right) => MyClass3(left.id, Some(right.value), Some(right.value))
}
```

Comment: it is python pandas, not scala

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.merge` has in parameter `indicator` which

> If True, adds a column to output DataFrame called “_merge” with information on the source of each row.

This can be used to check if there is a match

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value' : ['a','b']},index=[2,3])

# creates a new column `_merge` with values `right_only`, `left_only` or `both`
merged = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', right_index=True, left_index=True, indicator=True) 
merged['new_value'] = merged.loc[(merged['_merge'] == 'both'), 'value']
merged = merged.drop('_merge', axis=1)
```